# Can't run chmod on a bin file

Tags: macos, chmod

I am trying to install the android NDK on OSX 10.10. Even though the file is there it keeps returning "No such file or directory"

```
user$ ls
acs                 git-media               npm
acs-debug               github                  ti
alloy                   javascripting               tishadow
android-ndk-r10d-darwin-x86_64.bin  n                   titanium
git-it                  node
user$ sudo chmod a+x android-ndk-r10c-darwin-x86_64.bin
chmod: android-ndk-r10c-darwin-x86_64.bin: No such file or directory
user$
```

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the output of ls disagrees with you: android-ndk-r10c in your chmod, and android-ndk-r10d in ls.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the mistake on my part. I usually pay attention to detail better than this.